# My MS Access query of a query is not returning rows that have a null value in a field

Tags: ms-access, null

I have one query, called qry_sub_Loop, that uses a left join and has a null value in a derived field called Next_Home_Stop as a result of the left join.

I am having problems in other queries based off qry_sub_Loop.

### As a test to isolate the problem I have tried:

1. select * from qry_sub_Loop where Next_Home_Stop is null
2. select * from qry_sub_Loop where Asset='C-5M-000001'

C-5M-000001 is an Asset that has some values in Next_Home_Stop in some rows and null in other rows

Query 1) does not return any records. Query 2) only returns the rows where Asset='C-5M-000001' and Next_Home_Stop is not null.

---

```
table: arrival
- MissionID (text) 
- ArrivalTime (double) 
- DepartureTime (double) 
- DepartureLocation (text) 
- ArrivalLocation (text) 
- Asset (text) 

table: aircraft
- Asset (text), 
- Home (text)
```

---

Query:

```sql
select
    aircraft.Home, aircraft.Asset, arrival.DepartureTime,
    min(arrival_1.ArrivalTime) as Next_Home_Stop,
    max(arrival_2.ArrivalTime) as LastStop
From
    arrival as arrival_1
    right join ((aircraft
                 inner join arrival 
                    on arrival.DepartureLocation = aircraft.Home and
                       arrival.Asset = aircraft.Asset)
          inner join arrival as arrival_2
             on arrival_2.Asset = arrival.Asset and
                arrival_2.ArrivalTime > arrival.DepartureTime) 
        on arrival_1.Asset = arrival.Asset and
           arrival_1.ArrivalTime > arrival.DepartureTime and
           arrival_1.ArrivalLocation = arrival.DepartureLocation
group by ...
```

Comment: Can you show us the table structures (which fields are in which table) and how you joined the tables. It's difficult to say why this happens without seeing the queries.

Comment: put the screenshot of your table with data

Comment: I cant do screen shots because the query is on a stand alone machine that has restricted use

Comment: table: arrival fields: MissionID (text), ArrivalTime (double), DepartureTime (double), DepartureLocation (text), ArrivalLocation (text), Asset (text) table: aircraft fields: Asset (text), Home (text)

Comment: qry: select aircraft.Home, aircraft.Asset, arrival.DepartureTime, min(arrival_1.ArrivalTime) as Next_Home_Stop, max(arrival_2.ArrivalTime) as LastStop  From arrival as arrival_1 right join ((aircraft inner join arrival on arrival.DepartureLocation=aircraft.Asset and arrival.Asset=aircraft.Asset) inner join arrival as arrival_2 on arrival_2.Asset=arrival.Asset and arrival_2.ArrivalTime>arrival.DepartureTime) on arrival_1.Asset=arrival.Asset and arrival_1.ArrivalTime>arrival.DepartureTime and arrival_1.ArrivalLocation=arrival.DepartureLocation group by  ...

Comment: **UPDATE**  The qry_sub_Loop does not actually contain the rows with the null example. I thought it did because in the Access datasheet view I filtered to the home base that should have the null values and I see them. However when I sort the whole datasheet on that homebase, I do not see them. Why would a filter in the datasheet view show the row with the null value when they are not there to begin with?

Answer (score 3):

Examine the `Next_Home_Stop` values returned by `qry_sub_Loop`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Next_Home_Stop FROM qry_sub_Loop;
```

Is a Null returned by that query?  My guess is no, because you said query #2 returns values which are not Null.  Because `Next_Home_Stop` is actually `min(arrival_1.ArrivalTime)`, it can not include both Null and non-Null values.

`Min(ArrivalTime)` can return Null in only 2 situations:

1. All `ArrivalTime` values are Null.
2. There are now rows for `Min()` to evaluate.

If `ArrivalTime` includes any non-Null values, `Min()` will ignore the Null values and give you the minimum non-Null value.

Comment: The select distinct query did not return any nulls. There are nulls in qry_sub_Loop in that column. There are no nulls in the arrival table. The nulls in qry_sub_Loop is the result of the outter join conditions, particularly arrival_1.ArrivalLocation=arrival.DepartureLocation

Answer (score 1):

Because the **NULL values** in the joined rows are **placed** into the result set at such a **late stage in query processing**, you cannot test them as NULL values within the query itself.

so for retrieving null values you can do like this

```
     SELECT * FROM qry_sub_Loop 
     where 
     Next_Home_Stop 
     NOT IN               //you have to explicitly look for null
     (select Next_Home_Stop from qry_sub_Loop );
```

Comment: When I perform this query I get a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this applies to your query, but a common problem with outer joins occurs when you have a condition on the outer table

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
   A
   LEFT JOIN B
       ON A.X = B.X
WHERE
   B.Y = 'something'
```

This query will never yield empty rows for the table B, since the condition would not be fulfilled for them. Including the condition in the join condition does the trick:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
   A
   LEFT JOIN B
       ON (A.X = B.X AND B.Y = 'something')
```

Now rows of table A will be returned even when no matching rows exist in table B.

---

**UPDATE**

The join condition

```
arrival.DepartureLocation = aircraft.Asset
```

is wrong. You should compare the `DepartureLocation` with another `Location`, not with an `Asset`

Comment: You are correct. I had to copy manually between screens. It actually is arrival.DepartureLocation=aircraft.Home.